# want to fill a textbox dynamically in jsp page

Tags: jsp

want to create a application using jsp pages such that it takes a value from user in a textbox and on the basis of that value it retrives other values from database and fill other textboxes with that retrived values

Comment: Your requirement is very vague. Can you please elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a HTML form and put it in `search.jsp`:

   ```
   <form action="search" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="query">
       <input type="submit">
   </form>
   ```
2. Create a Java class which `extends HttpServlet` and does the desired business task:

   ```
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       String query = request.getParameter("query");
       Data data = someDAOClass.find(query);
       request.setAttribute("data", data); // Will be available in EL by ${data}
       request.getRequestDispatcher("search.jsp").forward(request, response); // Return back to JSP page.
   }
   ```

   Map this servlet on an `url-pattern` of `/search` in `web.xml` so that it will be executed then the form in the JSP is submitted.
3. Extend the form with the input fields which should display this data. Just fill the `value` attribute of the input elements with the desired information.

   ```
   <form action="somethingelse" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="id" value="${fn:escapeXml(data.id)}" />
       <input type="text" name="name" value="${fn:escapeXml(data.name)}" />
       <input type="text" name="email" value="${fn:escapeXml(data.email)}" />
       <input type="text" name="age" value="${fn:escapeXml(data.age)}" />
       ...
   </form>
   ```

   The `fn:escapeXml` is by the way there to prevent XSS.